# how to overload a task in the controller - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 tasks in my controller that perform 2 very different actions.

The first task provides functionality to my search bar - it displays data the user requests to search for in the search field.

The second task simply returns a view, the view isn't relevant to the question.

The search bar's function will only work if I call the "index" task of my controller. The documentation doesn't explain why you have to put the search bar functionality in the index task, but you have to otherwise you will get exceptions.

My issue is that I already have code in my index task - what can I do to have 2 index controllers? I've tried overloading it directly in the controller and it didn't work.

Here's the code I currently have for reference:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
        var course = from m in _context.Course
                     select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            course = course.Where(s => s.CourseName.Contains(searchString));
        }
     
        return View(await course.ToListAsync());
}

// GET: Course
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Course.ToListAsync());
}
```

My front end code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SEWebPage03</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar-container">
            <ul class="navbar-items">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Course" asp-action="Index">Courses</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Professor" asp-action="Index">Professors</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <form asp-controller="Course" asp-action="Index">
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="SearchString">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

When trying to change the name to my task that returns a view, I get this error
(I changed the name of the task to testing):

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Testing' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>
> /Views/Course/Testing.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Testing.cshtml
> /Pages/Shared/Testing.cshtml

Comment: If you are bound to use the index for your search bar, why dont you use for the other index a different method? Why do you actually need 2 index?

Comment: Can you post also the frontend code? as @nalnpir said you don't need to be bound to "index", you can create a method called "Search" or something else and you can overload methods from controller putting HttpPost/HttpGet attributes to it

Comment: @Leo  thank you for the suggestions! I have tried renaming the methods on both - I get errors when I rename the method responsible for search to "Search" and I also get errors when I rename the other index function that returns a view. I'm new to all this and don't quite understand why it is like that. And yes, Ill update my post with front end code!

Comment: Also, I updated my post with what happens when I try to change the name of my other method that simply returns a view

Comment: @mjwills ? Yes, and if you read the comment below it you would see I updated my post with the error. hard to format a code in stack overflow comments.

Comment: @izzyk I have updated my answer.I think you can change your asp-action in form,and then you can change the actionName in controller,If you want to return to other view in action,you can add ViewName in return View("ViewName").

Answer (score 0):

You can change your asp-action in your form:

Change

```
<form asp-controller="Course" asp-action="Index">
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="SearchString">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        </form>
```

to

```
 <form asp-controller="Course" asp-action="Search">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="SearchString">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                </p>
            </form>
```

And then you need to change your ActionName and the ViewName you return:

Change

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
        var course = from m in _context.Course
                     select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            course = course.Where(s => s.CourseName.Contains(searchString));
        }
     
        return View(await course.ToListAsync());
}
```

to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string searchString)
{
        var course = from m in _context.Course
                     select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            course = course.Where(s => s.CourseName.Contains(searchString));
        }
     
        return View("Index",await course.ToListAsync());
}
```